# how to parse nested json object with the same name with gson

Tags: java, gson, android

How to parse this json Object, where one "data" object, contains another "data" object in Java? Thanks.

```
{
      "id": "40469557",
      "data": {
        "id": "457073",
        "data": {
          "test_id": "123"
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Parsing this Json below.Explanation added after every getter.

```
{
      "id": "40469557",
      "data": {
      "id": "457073",
      "data": {
       "test_id": "123"
        }
      }
}
```

> This is the way how to get data from above JSON.

```
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
     jsonObject.getString("id").toString()//return id value
     jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getString("id").toString();//Return id value inside data object
     jsonObject.getJSONObject("data")..getJSONObject("data").getString("test_id").toString();
//Return test_id value inside data object in data object
```

//Ask if anything is not clear.

Comment: I am using GsonConverterFactory with Retrofit, how to do it that way?